# Reading the status of 48v connection with arduino

Tags: arduino

I have an arcade crane machine that has 3 DC motors that all run at 48v, i would like to connect an Arduino in parallel with the motor that lifts the claw up and down so i can see which direction the motor is going in so it will update a strip of WS2815 addressable leds that serve as the attract mode lights. The machine's main control PCB has 7 relays, one for each direction and for the claw solenoid, it basically flips the polarity when it needs to go the other way.

I was thinking about using resistors to lower the 48V to 5v and then connecting both wires to the Arduino's digital pins, then i could read them as HIGH or LOW, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, a simple resistor divider is all you need.
If you can't get exact resistor values shown, the two things are the ratio to divide it down to 3.3V max and the total resistance so that you aren't pulling a ton of current from the 48V source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Uh03.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>